# Powershell character number limitation in New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute <String>

Tags: powershell

I'm currently having issues using the New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute **String** command.

The issue occurs when the passed **String** exceeds 260 characters. I tested this using the following code:

Code that works:

```
# create app object
$real_time_task_action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

$current_date = Get-Date

# create base trigger object
$real_time_base_trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger `
    -Once `
    -At $current_date `
    -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1)

# create tasks
$real_time_base_task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $real_time_task_action -Trigger $real_time_base_trigger

# register tasks
Register-ScheduledTask PerfAlgRealTimeBase -InputObject $real_time_base_task
```

Code that errors out:

```
# create app object
$real_time_task_action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

$current_date = Get-Date

# create base trigger object
$real_time_base_trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger `
    -Once `
    -At $current_date `
    -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1)

# create tasks
$real_time_base_task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $real_time_task_action -Trigger $real_time_base_trigger

# register tasks
Register-ScheduledTask PerfAlgRealTimeBase -InputObject $real_time_base_task
```

This is the actual error (which I feel is somewhat generic):

```
Register-ScheduledTask : The task XML contains a value which is incorrectly formatted or out of range.
```

My question then is: is there a way to go around this character limitation? Ultimately I would like to execute Task actions with **Strings** with more than 260 characters.

Comment: With the parameter `-Execute` you specify the path to an executable file. If that path is too long you may use a script located in a shorter path to circumvent this limit.

Comment: Look into Subst.exe, Hard Links and Junction Points. All three give you options to shorten total path length via substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, paths are limited to 260 characters in Windows per default. To work around this, you can either:

1. Prefix every path with `\\?\`, e. g. `\\?\D:\very long path`, to make it an extended-length path ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation)). Or
2. Enable long paths in Windows 10 (since v1607) by changing the registry ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later)):

   ```bsh
   Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem' -Name 'LongPathsEnabled' -Value 1
   ```

   A reboot is required to make this change effective for all processes.